# Rendering PDF documents containing visual signatures using Jpedal

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, jpedal

I'm using Jpedal (LGPL version 4.48b55) to render the pages of a document containing signatures with visual representation activated. However, those signatures appear with an overimposed question mark and the text "Signature Not Verified".

If I and visualize the file through Adobe Acrobat Reader, I get a green tick and a text saying the "signature is valid" (since I included the certificate authority of the signatures in the list).

Is there any way to force jPedal to validate the signatures with a list of valid certificate authorities, so it renders the signatures as valid?

Comment: did you import your certificate into the java keystore?

Comment: Is the Certificate in the PDF or the cache?

Comment: The root ca is in the system keystore (in the CryptoAPI since I'm working on Windows), do I need to include it into a java specific one for jPedal?

Comment: you need to pass in the key/cert when you open the file public void openPdfFile(String filename, Certificate certificate, PrivateKey key)

Comment: Is that a commercial version functionality? I'm using the LGPL version and I don't see that function in the PDFDecoder o PDFReader API...

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a certificate in Java, you need to install it first on the Java Keystore. Use the tool [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) provided with Java runtime to accomplish this task.

From the page "[The Most Common Java Keytool Keystore Commands](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)":

```
# Import New CA into Trusted Certs
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /path/to/ca/ca.pem -alias CA_ALIAS -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

If you want your application to use the keystore from the OS directly, you will have to specify a specific provider for this, different from the default.

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#KeystoreLocation):

> Keystore implementations are provider-based. More specifically, the
>   application interfaces supplied by KeyStore are implemented in terms
>   of a "Service Provider Interface" (SPI). That is, there is a
>   corresponding abstract KeystoreSpi class, also in the java.security
>   package, which defines the SPI methods that "providers" must
>   implement.

And also:

> There is a built-in default implementation, provided by Sun
>   Microsystems. It implements the keystore as a file, utilizing a
>   proprietary keystore type (format) named "JKS".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I imported it successfully, but unfortunately I still get the "Signature Not Verified" message and the question mark...

Comment: Since it is an LGPL project, I would recommend stepping into the code, maybe this way you can have a better idea of what is going wrong.